# I get error when I try to check my MySQLdb connector in Django shell

Tags: mysql, django

```
 60 DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.mysql'
 61 DATABASE_NAME = 'mysite'
 62 DATABASE_USER = 'root'
 63 DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'password'
 64 DATABASE_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
 65 DATABASE_PORT = '3306'
 66 
 67 DATABASES = {
 68     'default': {
 69         'ENGINE': DATABASE_ENGINE,
 70         'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
 71         'USER': DATABASE_USER,
 72         'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
 73         'HOST': DATABASE_HOST,
 74         'PORT': DATABASE_PORT,
 75     }
 76 }
```

Under the settings.py above in my django project,I tried to see if DB adapter(MySQLdb : http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) is working OK with my django configuration.

But I ended up with meeting some kind of error I have never seen before like this.

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> a = connection()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'DefaultConnectionProxy' object is not callable
```

I installed mysql on my machine, of course, and since I've done this configuration before and it worked at that time, I am confused what did I have done it wrong this time.

I know what error messages would be like when the error is something due to django's settings.py configuration. But I totally don't get what's going on with this error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The object django.db.connection represents the default database connection. To use the database connection, call connection.cursor() to get a cursor object. Then, call cursor.execute(sql, [params]) to execute the SQL and cursor.fetchone() or cursor.fetchall() to return the resulting rows."*

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

So, if you need connection object you should do:

```
connection = django.db.connection
```

Django use persistent connection to database, so you no need to initialize it.